# Scrollable Textview or listview within a Scrollable View

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been pondering this for a while now, is it possible to have a scrollable TextView or ListView within a ScrollView of the whole layout?

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/linearTest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_text_padding"
        android:text="@string/main_introduction" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The textview would not scroll within the scrollview in the example here, but if the scrollview is taken out and the textview is given the method new ScrollingMovementMethod(), the textview would scroll.

I know that there should not be a scrollable within a scrollable view as it creates conflict for the device to figure out which scroll to be invoked when a user interacts.

Is there a alternative to this?
Thanks

Comment: maxLines="2" doesn't make much sense, in this case

Comment: it does, if you wanted to see only 2 lines but scroll for the rest of the text. This is just an example for what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: true, listview is scrollable, but if you put it into a scrollview, if you encapsulate listview into scrollview it would have errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is method by which we can make the text in textview scrollble.

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: yeah, this would only work for textviews that are not within a scrollview. I've talked about it in my post. So this does not answer my question

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna let the TextView scroll instead the ScrollView, you can create your own ScrollView which extend from ScrollView, and Override the method `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and change the return value `return false;` but I can't understand why you wanna do this, because the ScrollView in here is meaningless.

Comment: update: If you wanted to see only two lines of each item, a better design is show the whole content after user click this item.

Comment: That was just an example. i'm thinking of creating a layout that has a fixed width or height and have certain parts scroll in devices with small screens and also to feed my curiosity